# Why EF can't sort items by the order of another collection and how to workaround?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, entity-framework-6

I have been trying to sort a LINQ query using a list of strings. I am querying student terms and including TermCourses.
The code throws the following error:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 IndexOf(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

I have done this kind of sorting using `DataTables` where I have just rows but not in EF and a tree of objects.

How do I work around this issue?

Here is my Code:

```
private static readonly List<string> SortingOrder =
   new List<string>()
   {
        "Fall",
        "Spring",
        "Summer"
   };

using (var context = new EUContext())
{
    var tmp = context.Terms.Include(x=>x.TermCourses)
        .OrderBy(x => x.AcademicYear)
        .ThenBy(x => SortingOrder.IndexOf(x.TermRegistered))
        .Where(x => x.StudentID == studentId && x.DepartmentID == departmentId);
    return tmp.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Why? Because LINQ can't translate everything to valid SQL. Why it works with DataTables? Because that is LINQ-To-Objects and doesn't need to be translated to SQL.

Comment: Are you able to change the database representation to use a numeric field instead of a string for the "term registered"? That would be the simplest solution.

Comment: the answer is as Tim said .IndexOf( is a c# funcation which it cant not convert to sql, also its confusing what your doing, just include the SQL and someone will help you convert to valid linq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to sort on the database by a method that is available in your code/RAM only. You need to transfer control of the sorting back to your local computer:

```
private static readonly List<string> SortingOrder =
   new List<string>()
   {
        { "Fall" },
        { "Spring" },
        { "Summer" }
   };

using (var context = new EUContext())
{
    // this part will query the database
    var tmp = context.Terms
                     .Include(x=>x.TermCourses)
                     .Where(x => x.StudentID == studentId && x.DepartmentID == departmentId)

                     // this will transfer controll to your local machine
                     .AsEnumerable() 

                     // sort on your local machine by the data you have in your RAM
                     .OrderBy(x => x.AcademicYear)
                     .ThenBy(x => SortingOrder.IndexOf(x.TermRegistered));

    return tmp.ToList();
}
```

Comment: _"transfer control to your local machine"_ can be translated with _use Linq-To-Objects_, so execute the rest of the query in memory. Would be interesting to know how to do this with pure EF/SQL in case there are a huge number of records to sort.

Comment: Thank you @nvoigt for the answer. I've marked it as the accepted answer. I have found away to do it purely using LINQ without transferring the control back to memory.